# DISCORD.JS bot goes offline in some shards but not all

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Whats wrong with my sharding? The bot goes offline in some guilds but not all.

```js
const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');
const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', { token: 'TOKEN' });

manager.on('shardCreate', shard => console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`));
manager.spawn();
```

Comment: Don't quote me but I think shards deactivate and go offline if there is nothing in them.. So if there is no users enough for shards it does deactivate them.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. does the bot just magically go online if the command is used? that doesn't make sense.